# Disable non-ajax button on submit

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I need to disable the button on submit and enable it back when action is completed. I have the following codes for my button. When I click on the button, the button just disabled and the action is never called. Anyone have any idea?

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Create"
       styleClass="commandButton" id="maintenance_command_add"
       action="#{pc_Ma1001.doMa1001_command_addAction}"
       onclick="jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('ui-state-disabled')" 
       oncomplete="jQuery(this).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled')" 
       ajax="false">
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onSubmit instead of onClick